# Thread-safe Priority Queue for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, priority-queue

I'm looking for a priority queue implemented in Delphi that would work well in a multi-threaded environment.

Ideally lock-free, or designed for multi-threaded inserts/deletes with something better than a locked wrapper around a single-threaded implementation (which I already have).

The specificity is that in normal operation, there would be only adds, deletes, and notifications when the top (highest priority item) changes, while "pop" operations of the highest priority item should be very infrequent.

It would be used for a watchdog/timeout thread monitoring tasks, being executed in other threads, those task are expected to terminate normally most of the time, so they would just be added/removed from the queue. The timeout thread would essentially be waiting on the next timeout event, hence the need for notifications when the top-priority event changes.

The tasks are handled by scripts, which can be safely terminated at any time.

If there are better algorithms for this than a priority queue, they could be good answers too!

**Edit:** following a remark by Martin James, another specificity is that there are relatively few different timeout values, and for each timeout value, the problem becomes that of a FIFO queue.

Comment: Why "locked wrapper around a single-threaded implementation" is not good enough for this task?

Comment: What are the performance constraints that make a lock based solution not appropriate?

Comment: @Pol: It's not good enough because I already have one (as said in the post)

Comment: @David: there can be an awful lot of tasks being started and stopped at any time, including tasks which can be very short. My benchmarks with my lock-based solution show it being a bottleneck to scaling beyond 10-12 task-threads, as all tasks end up locking the priority queue twice, once for adding, once for deleting. Ideally I would like it to scale to something like 32 to 48 task-threads.

Comment: Sometimes lock free solutions can be worse of course.

Comment: So, there are multiple threads modifying an ordered list and notifying a thread that's timing out an item at the front of the queue.  This is err.. 'not nice' to do in a lock-free fashion.  The notifications would need to queue and the items they reference may no longer exist by the time the notification is processed.  The items may have been freed and created with the same instance value by the time the notification is processed.  It's all nasty!  Which operation on your current implementation is causing the performance problem?

Comment: OK, one suggestion - don't delete them from the list, just mark them as 'deletion pending' in some internal state enum.  Eventually, the timeout-thread will get at them and can delete them then.

Comment: @EricGrange - when items are added, are they always added with the same timeout value and so are always added to the end of the queue, or do the timeout intervals vary a lot?

Comment: Julian M. Bucknall wrote a C# [lock-free limited priority queue](http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockFreeLimitedPriorityQ.html). Java has a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). Another C# [Thread-safePriorityQueue](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Thread-safePriorityQueueC.aspx)

Comment: @MartinJames: the most costly operation is maintaining the internal list sorted (lookup+insertion on add, lookup+delete on delete). Currently using an array, linked-list displaced the pressure on the memory manager, haven't tried yet to pool the linked-list elements, as I felt my approach wouldn't be "top-notch" even that way.

Comment: @MartinJames: timeout delta is almost always the same, or at least comes from a very limited set of value... yes, that's the point I had overlooked, I could probably have a watchdog per-timeout value, each would then only maintain a FIFO queue! Should combine well with "deletion pending" too. Post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

[Julian Bucknall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806/boyetboy) (Author of "Tomes of Delphi: Algorithms and Data Structures" ) has recently announced the release of a Delphi XE version of [EZDSL](http://www.boyet.com/code/ezdsl304.zip)(a Delphi Structures Library) in his [Blog](http://blog.boyet.com/blog/ezdsl/ezdsl-for-delphi-xe/).

Unfortunately TThreadsafePriorityQueue (implemented in EZDSLPQu.PAS) is lock based.

I can't help sharing the good news and my other intent is a call for his contribution in answering the question.

Comment: I've been using my own personally-ported EZDSL since forever, and if I trust anything to start with as a base, it's EZDSL.

Answer (score 1):

My framework architecture is completely built around priority threaded queues - that's the only threading model I use (http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_overview.htm). A steep learning curve, but it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single que you could use one queue for each priority.

The OmnithreadLibrary contains thread safe queues:
http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/

http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/

Comment: Multiple single-priority queues are not really a solution. All 'popping' operations get complicated immensely. (Pushing, OTOH, is simple.) In my mid-term plan is a TODO saying "check possibility of lock-free priority queue" but that will not happen in the next few months.